# React navigation native web routes not working when deployed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I am using NavigationContainer with the linking prop to implement web routes in React Native.

```
const linking = {
    prefixes: [
      'https://***',
    ],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Home: '',
        ReserveAndPay: 'details',
      },
    },
  };
```

The `details` route can be accessed locally at:
http://localhost:19006/details

but when deployed
https://***/details
is giving a 404 error.

Am I missing a setting in the linking object?

edit: site is built for web using Expo and deployed to an AWS S3 bucket

Comment: I still need to figure out why, but using the same build command and deploying to AWS Amplify solved the issue. (I can navigate to the /details route above) Might there be an additional setting for Expo web apps when deploying to S3 that I missed?